# pdo ограничение количества записей в базе

Tags: php, mysql

Задача хранить некую статистику на 30 дней в БД. Дабы не нагружать ее лишним хламом требуется в базе иметь не более 30 записей. То есть при добавлении новой удаляется самая старая. Возможно реализовать подобное средствами myAdmin или pdo? Читал что тригеры могут помочь, но так и не получилось их реализовать под мою задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть имеется некая:

```
CREATE TABLE stat ( dt TIMESTAMP
                       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                  , stat_data SOMETYPE );
```

Сразу заполняем её нужным количеством записей:

```
INSERT INTO stat (statdata) SELECT NULL; -- и так 30 раз
```

Добавление новой и удаление самой старой записи выполняется запросом:

```
UPDATE stat
SET statdata = @new_data
ORDER BY dt ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Всё собственно... если надо увеличить глубину хранения - добавляем недостающее количество записей, если надо, наоборот, уменьшить - удаляем необходимое количество самых старых.